# Rails 3- find_by not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, findby

I have a strange problem.

I have two models Users and roles with a many to many relationships between them. 
I want to filter the roles with name 'Administrator' within the role collection of a user.

In the model this code

```
puts self.roles.to_s
```

Prints to screen: 
    [Role id: 1, name: "Administrator", created_at: "2012-01-22 21:55:45", updated_at: "2012-01-22 21:55:45"]

But this code

```
puts self.roles.find_by_name('Administrator').to_s
```

doesn't print anything. And this one:

```
puts self.roles.find_by_name('Administrator').nil?
```

prints true!

Why isn't my find_by_name method not working?
I tryied it in the console and it works well.

My code snippet is the following:

```
puts self.roles.to_s
puts self.roles.find_by_name('Administrator').to_s
puts self.roles.find_by_name('Administrator').nil?
```

And the output is the following:

```
[Role id: 1, name: "Administrator", created_at: "2012-01-22 21:55:45", updated_at: "2012-01-22 21:55:45"]
<none>
true
```

What am I doing wrong?? It has to be something stupid.
This code is located in a validate method, so it is executed before the user is saved.

Comment: do you have a name column in both tables?

Comment: Is the new role in the database when you're calling `find_by_name`?

Comment: Can you post your habtm configuration please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that you are doing this in a validation **before the model is saved**. This is why it's failing. Since the `User` is not yet saved, it doesn't have an `id` in your database, so there's no way for it to search your associations.

The reason the first line works (`self.roles.to_s`) is that Rails memorizes any roles you add to your user, but does not save them to the database until you save the user. Once you save the user, your second/third lines would work fine:

```
user = User.new
user.roles << Role.first
user.roles
# => [#<Role id: 1, name: "Administrator" ...>]
user.roles.find_by_name("Administrator")
# => nil
user.save  # This inserts both the new user AND the associations
user.roles.find_by_name("Administrator")
# => #<Role id: 1, name: "Administrator" ...>
```

If you have to work with this in your validations, you might try using Enumerable's `find` method to search the `roles` array instead:

```
user = User.new
user.roles << Role.first
user.roles
# => [#<Role id: 1, name: "Administrator" ...>]
user.roles.find { |role| role.name == "Administrator" }
# => #<Role id: 1, name: "Administrator" ...>
user.roles.find { |role| role.name == "Foo" }
# => nil
```